Shopify - Product With Multiple Variants, If One Of Them Is Sold Out Everything Else Is Sold Out Too
In my store I have a product that has the following variants: color, size and length. 
For example I have the following quantities (grouped by size) for this product:

color: blue, size: 40/54, length: 32, quantity: 5
color: blue, size: 40/54, length: 34, quantity: 5
color: blue, size: 40/54, length: 36, quantity: 5



color: blue, size: 42/56, length: 32, quantity: 5
color: blue, size: 42/56, length: 34, quantity: 5
color: blue, size: 42/56, length: 36, quantity: 5



color: blue, size: 44/58, length: 32, quantity: 0
color: blue, size: 44/58, length: 34, quantity: 5
color: blue, size: 44/58, length: 36, quantity: 5

As you can see only the product with size 44/58 and length 32 is sold out, but in my store it displays that everything is available and if the user selects the size 44/58 with the length 32 a random length is chosen for him. How can I fix this? I have a third part theme that doesn't have support and I can't change it with another theme.
Here's the code of the file swatch.liquid that manages the display of the variants:
{% comment %}
  Set the extension of your color files below. Use 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg' or 'gif'.
{% endcomment %}
{% assign file_extension = 'png' %}
{% capture variantsswatch %} {% endcapture %}
{% if swatch == "Color" %}
    {% capture variantsswatch %}{{ 'products.variants.color' | t }}{% endcapture %}
{% elsif swatch == "Size" %}
    {% capture variantsswatch %}{{ 'products.variants.size' | t }}{% endcapture %}
{% else %}
    {% capture variantsswatch %}{{ swatch }}{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}

{% if swatch == blank %}
    <div class="swatch error">
        <p>You must include the snippet swatch.liquid with the name of a product option.</p>
        <p>Use: <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'name of your product option here' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
        <p>Example: <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'Colore' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
    </div>
{% else %}
{% assign found_option = false %}
{% assign is_color = false %}
{% assign is_lunghezza = false %}
{% assign option_index = 0 %}
{% assign indexChild = 0 %}
{% for option in product.options %}
    {% if option == swatch %}
        {% assign found_option = true %}
        {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}
        {% assign indexChild = forloop.index %}
        <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            .proVariants .selector-wrapper:nth-child({{ indexChild }}){display: none;}
            .maxus-productdetail__options:not(:last-child) {
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        {% assign downcased_option = swatch | downcase %}
        {% if downcased_option contains 'colore' or downcased_option contains 'colour' or downcased_option contains 'color' %}
            {% assign is_color = true %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if downcased_option contains 'lunghezza' or downcased_option contains 'length' %}
            {% assign is_lunghezza = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% unless found_option %}

{% else %}
<div class="maxus-productdetail__options{% unless section.settings.spd_style == "pd_style2" %} {% endunless %} {% if is_color %}var-colore{% endif %}">
    <div class="{% if settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio2" %} swatch_radio1 {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio3" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio4" %} swatch_radio3 {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle2" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_gallery" %} swatch_rectangle1 {% endif %}swatch clearfix {% if settings.po_style == "po_swatchs" %} align-center flex engoc-flex-wrap{% endif %}" data-option-index="{{ option_index }}">
        <!-- <p class="text-uppercase title_variant" style="border-bottom:none;padding-bottom:none;">{{ variantsswatch }} </p> -->
        {% if variantsswatch == 'Colore' %}
        <p class="text-uppercase title_variant" style="border-bottom:none;padding-bottom:none;">Colore </p>
        {% elsif variantsswatch == 'Taglia' %}
        <p class="text-uppercase title_variant" style="border-bottom:none;padding-bottom:none;">Taglia </p>
        {% elsif variantsswatch == 'Lunghezza' %}
        <p class="text-uppercase title_variant" style="margin-left:6px;border-bottom:none;padding-bottom:none;">Lunghezza </p>
        {% endif %}
        {% assign values = '' %}
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% assign value = variant.options[option_index] %}
            {% unless values contains value %}
                {% assign values = values | join: ',' %}
                {% assign values = values | append: ',' | append: value %}
                {% assign values = values | split: ',' %}

                {% assign unique_variant_id = variant.id | append: '-' | append: value | append: '-' | append: option_index %}

                {% assign available = false %}
                {% if variant.available %}
                    {% assign available = true %}  
                {% else %}
                    {% comment %}
                        Check if any other variant with the same size is available
                    {% endcomment %}
                    {% for other_variant in product.variants %}
                        {% if other_variant != variant and other_variant.options[option_index] == value and other_variant.available %}
                            {% assign available = true %}
                            {% break %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                    {% if is_color %}
                      <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" data-style="square" class="maxus-color none color {{ value | handle }} {% if available %} available {% else %}soldout{% endif %}" {% if available %}{% else %}data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  data-html="true" data-original-title="Coming Soon <br> NOTIFY ME"{% endif %}>
                        <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if forloop.first %} checked{% endif %} {% unless available %}disabled{% endunless %} />
                        {% if settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio3"  %}
                            <label class="radio_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                <label class="color_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                </label>
                                <span class="text_color">{{ value }}</span>
                            </label>  
                        {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio2"  %}
                            <div class="radio_style2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="{{value}}">
                                <label class="color_style2" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-image: url({{ variant.image.src | product_img_url: 'grande' }}); background-size: cover;">
                                </label>
                            </div>  
                        {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle1"  %}
                            <label class="rectangle_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                <span class="text_rec">{{ value }}</span>
                            </label>
                        {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_gallery"  %}
                            <div class="swatch_gallery">
                                <label class="bg_image" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | file_url }}); background-size: cover;">
                                </label>
                            </div> 
                        {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "default" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio4" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle2"   %}
                            <div class="  border-color ">
                                <label class="link_color" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | file_url }}); background-size: cover;">
                                </label>
                            </div> 
                        {% endif %}
                        </div>

                    {% elsif is_lunghezza %}
                        <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" data-style="square" class="maxus-color none length colora-nero {{ value | handle }} {% if available %} available {% else %}soldout{% endif %}" {% if available %}{% else %}data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  data-html="true" data-original-title="Coming Soon <br> NOTIFY ME"{% endif %}>
                          <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% unless available %} disabled{% endunless %} />
                          {% if settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio2" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio3" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio4" %}
                              <label class="radio_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                  <label class="color_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" >
                                  </label>
                                  <span class="text_color">{{ value }}</span>
                              </label> 
                          {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle2" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_gallery" %}
                              <label class="rectangle_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                  <span class="text_rec">{{ value }}</span>
                              </label>
                          {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "default" %}
                              <label class="variant_other" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" >
                                  {{ value }}
                              </label>
                          {% endif %}
                      </div>
                    {% else %}
                      <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" data-style="square" class="maxus-color none taglia {{ value | handle }} {% if available %} available {% else %}soldout{% endif %}" {% if available %}{% else %}data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  data-html="true" data-original-title="Coming Soon <br> NOTIFY ME"{% endif %}>
                        <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}" {% unless available %} disabled{% endunless %} />
                        {% if settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio2" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio3" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_radio4" %}
                              <label class="radio_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                  <label class="color_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" >
  
                                  </label>
                                  <span class="text_color">{{ value }}</span>
                              </label> 
                          {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle1" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_rectangle2" or settings.swatch_style == "sw_gallery" %}
                              <label class="rectangle_style1" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
                                  <span class="text_rec">{{ value }}</span>
                              </label>
                          {% elsif settings.swatch_style == "default" %}
                              <label class="variant_other" for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" >
                                  {{ value }}
                              </label>
                          {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                
            {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endunless %}
{% endif %}

